# Cant cast RuntimeType to generic type

Tags: c#

I am constructing a type switch to change views in WPV and MVVM so this type switch looks like:

```
public class TypeSwitch
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Action<object>> matches = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>();

    public TypeSwitch Case<TType>(Action<TType> action)
    {
        matches.Add(typeof(TType), type =>
        {
            try
            {
                action((TType)type);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex); // invalid cast exception runtime type to other
            }
        });
        return this;
    }

    public void Switch(Type type)
    {
        matches[type](type);
    }
}
```

So its main purpose is to check type and execute action on switch according to type, sounds simple. But I am getting wrong casting exception that looks like:

> InvalidCastException: Unable To Cast Objects of type 'System.RuntimeType' to type 'App.ViewModels.RawEventDataFileStep'

and i do not know why and how to solve it.

My execution looks like:

```
    public ICommand PreviousStepCommand => new Command(p =>
    {
        Type activeWizardStep = this.WizardStepContext.GetType().UnderlyingSystemType;
        TypeSwitch step =
            new TypeSwitch()
                .Case((RawEventDataFileStep type) =>
                {
                    this.WizardStepContext = this.AddAdditionalInfoStepContext;
                    this.LabelFullTitle = $"{labelTitle}, {this.AddAdditionalInfoStepContext.StepTitle}";
                })
                .Case((RawEventDataAdditionalInfoStep type) => Logger.Warn("Next button in raw event data wizzard shold be disabled on last step"));
        Logger.Info($"Switching from {activeWizardStep} to next step");
        step.Switch(activeWizardStep);
    });
```

So basically I am stuck, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It looks like you're passing a `Type` here: `matches[type](type);` when you should probably be passing something else. After all, if we declare `type = typeof(Bus);` then we have an object (`type`) describing what a `Bus` object looks like. We can't convert that description to an actual `Bus` through casting (i.e. `(Bus)type;` won't work).

Comment: @Llama agreed - somewhere, there needs to be the *object* that should be used; I would expect perhaps `Switch(object obj) => matches[obj.GetType](obj);`

Comment: OP: What are you intending to convert, and how will that be specified? It seems like switched should be defined as Marc suggested, or perhaps as `public void Switch(Type type, object obj)`, or else there's nothing to convert.

Comment: I hate to say it, but: couldn't this whole thing be replaced more conveniently and more efficiently with a simple `switch` block or expression? or perhaps even just with polymorphism (as in: a `virtual`/`abstract` method)?

Comment: @Llama aye you were right, in switch method I should get object not type, and when called I am passing now existing class instance. Now it works, oh blind me.

Comment: @Marc Gravell and it will land in an abstract method, now I was just prototyping this ;)